# Regex and C++11, software or compiler wrong?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, g++

i'm trying to create a complex software in C++ using Regular expressions... Now i'm doing some tests, but i've got runtime error. I tried gcc 4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and latest CodeBlocks with compiler included (I think is MinGW porting of gcc 4.7). The Regular Expression is correct because i try that on this website http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and work. They need to recognize and addition. This is the software:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

string stringa;

int main()
{
        cin >> stringa;
        if (regex_match(stringa, regex("^[0-9]*\\+[0-9]*$", regex::ECMAScript))) //need to insert \\ to prevent escape sequence
        {
                cout << "Addition" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Not addition" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

When i run that, after insert input, i receive that error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what(): regex_error     Annullato (core dump creato)
```

The problem is my code or compiler?

Comment: `std::regex` is not implemented in g++4.7

Comment: Nice news though: `Newsflash: <regex> is now implemented on the GCC subversion trunk, it will be in GCC 4.9`